# Bounded solution for parabolic equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, heat-equation, regularity, semigroups-of-operators

Let $\Omega_T=(0,T) \times \Omega$, where $\Omega$ a bounded smooth domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T>0$. Let $a\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ and consider the heat equation
$$u_t=\Delta u + a(x)u, \;\; (t,x)\in \Omega_T ,$$
$$u|_{\partial \Omega}=0,$$
$$u(0,\cdot)=u_0.$$
Assume that the initial condition $u_0 \in H^2(\Omega)\cap H^1_0(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$, can we prove that the solution $u$ is such that $u_t \in L^\infty(\Omega_T)$ ?

I found some old results which use much of regularity on $a$ and $u_0$ based on maximum principles. Are there any other ways to prove such results under weaker assumptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the heat equation $Lu=u_t-\Delta u=0$ to guarantee boundedness of $u_t$ as $t$ tends to zero one has to demand more regularity from the initial function, e.g. $u_0\in C^{1,1}(\bar\Omega)$ (the first order derivatives are uniformly Lipschitz in $\Omega$).

As for the low order term, differentiating wrt $t$ we have that $u_t$ satisfies the same equation. So if $u_0,\Delta u_0\in L_\infty(\Omega)$ then $u_t|_{t=0}\in L_\infty(\Omega)$ and $u_t$ is bounded.

Denote $a_0=\|a\|_{L_\infty(\Omega)}$ and $v(t)=\|u\|_{L_\infty(\Omega_t)}$. For the first BVP $u_t-\Delta u=f$, $u|_{t=0}=u_0$ with zero boundary condition it follows that 
$$
v(t)\le t a_0 v(t)+\|u_0\|_{L_\infty(\Omega)}.
$$
From here for $T_0=1/(2a_0)$ it follows that $v(T_0)\le 2\|u_0\|_{L_\infty(\Omega)}$. For arbitrary $T$ the estimate $v(T)\le C\|u_0\|_{L_\infty(\Omega)}$ follows from step by step argument, where $C$ depends upon $T$ as well as on $a_0$. For the derivative it gives the estimate 
$$
\|u_t\|_{L_\infty(\Omega_T)}\le C(T,a_0)(\|u_0\|_{L_\infty(\Omega)}+\|\Delta u_0\|_{L_\infty(\Omega)}).
$$

Comment: Thank you @Andrew, I'm looking for further assumptions which imply the boundedness result. I think it is sufficient to see the boundedness of the solution and deduce the result for the time derivative.

Comment: Okey, in my case $Lu=u_t- \Delta u=f=au$. What is the assumption on $f$ to obtain the boundedness for $u$. I need some references on such results. Thanks.

Comment: I found that the assumption is $f\in L^\infty(\Omega_T)$ and this is the result we look for. See this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776017/bounded-data-means-bounded-solution-to-parabolic-pde

Comment: For the heat equation in a smooth bounded domain there exists the Green function $G$ of the first BVP. The solution with zero initial condition can be written as 
$$
u(x,t)=\int_0^t \int_\Omega G(x,y,t-\tau)f(y,\tau)\,dyd\tau.
$$
Also one can get the estimate $0<G(x,y,t)<Z(x-y,t)$, where $Z$ is the fundamental solution of the heat equation. From there the estimate 
$$
|u(x,t)|\le t \|f\|_{L_\infty(\Omega_t)}
$$ follows immediately.

Comment: Yes but $f$ in our case depends on the solution $f(t,x)=a(x)u(t,x)$, then we cannot deduce the result by this argument.

Comment: Do you agree with me or I'm wrong. Btw thanks.

Comment: I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I don't get the final result for arbitrary $T>T_0$.

Comment: Denote $u_1(x)=u(x,T_0)$. Since $u$ is a solution of the first BVP with  $u_t-\Delta u=a(x)u$, $u|_{t=T_0}=u_1$, one has $v(2T_0)\le \max(2\|u_1\|_{L_\infty(\Omega)},v(T_0))\le  4\|u_0\|_{L_\infty(\Omega)}$ etc.

Comment: I think it is not necessary to take the maximum in your last comment. We can do the same for the new BVP to obtain $v(2T_0)\leq 2 \|u_1\|_\infty$.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, I'm a bit confused coming back to this question. When we take $T_0=1/2a_0$ we obtain $v(T_0)\le 1/2 \; v(T_0)+\|u_0\|_\infty$. But why $v(T_0)<+\infty$  to deduce $v(T_0)\le 2\|u_0\|_\infty$.

Comment: @S.Maths For the heat equation $u_t-\Delta u=f$ and smooth bounded domain $\Omega$ there exists Green's function $G(x,t,y,\tau)=G(x,y,t-\tau)$ of the first BVP. The solution can be represented as 
$$
u(x,t)=\int_{\Omega}G(x,y,t)u_0(y)\,dy+\int_0^t\int_{\Omega}G(x,y,t-\tau)f(y,\tau)\,dyd\tau.
$$
For the equation $u_t-\Delta u=a(x)u$ one gets an integral equation 
$$
u(x,t)=\int_{\Omega}G(x,y,t)u_0(y)\,dy+\int_0^t\int_{\Omega}G(x,y,t-\tau)a_0(x)u(y,\tau)\,dyd\tau.
$$

Comment: @S.Maths From the well-known estimate $0<G(x,y,t)\le Ct^{-n/2}e^{-c(x-y)^2/t}$ it follows that for small $T>0$ the operator in the rhs is a contraction in $L_\infty(\Omega\times [0,T])$, so there exists a bounded solution $u$.

Comment: in my case $T$ is fixed and not necessarily small.

Comment: @S.Maths step by step argument. For one step it is enough to take small enough $T<T_0$.